What are typical payoffs of PRDCs?
I understand that in PRDCs (Power Reverse Dual-Currency note), client is long call spreads coupons on e.g. USDJPY (the FX carry pair). The PRDC is also callable by the issuer. I'd expect the call spreads to make dealers short skew / long vanna (although dampened by the callable option?)
However I also heard that PRDCs typically make dealers longer backend vega when spot is down. That is dealer long skew / short vanna dynamic. So I must be missing something in the payoff. What is it?
